# Backbone.js Can we not have any tagName?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I just started with backbone.js, and one thing that I noticed is that sometimes I do not want any `tagName` to contain/encapsulate my view's template code. If I leave it at `''` or `'span'`, I get unneccessary `div` and `span` in my code.

The alternative that I found is to remove the containing tag from my template (`<div class="photo_box">` in my example as shown below), and use that as the `tagName` in my view. Most of the time, this tag will contain a class (`.photo_box`), and I still have to perform an `addClass` to (this.el). I dont really like scattering up my template code.

Is there another way?

**JS**

```
// Views
PhotoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',

    render: function() {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(photo) {
            $(this.el).append(new PhotoListItemView({ model: photo }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

PhotoListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',

    template: _.template($('#tpl-PhotoListItemView').html()),

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
        return this;
    }


});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-PhotoListItemView">
                <div class="photo_box">
                    <div class="photo_container">
                        <img src="img/profiling/<%= photo_id %>.jpg" class='photo' />
                    </div>
                </div>
</script>
```

**Result**

```
<div id="photo_list">
    <span>
        <span>
                    <div class="photo_box">
                        <div class="photo_container">
                            <img src="img/profiling/f_001.jpg" class="photo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </span>
        <span>
                    <div class="photo_box">
                        <div class="photo_container">
                            <img src="img/profiling/f_002.jpg" class="photo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case you simply want `tagName` to be a `"div"`, with the class name `"photo_box"`. So do that and remove that div from your template.

Comment: DIV inside SPAN? What are you doing? If it's a list use UL/LI.

Comment: I agree with the comments above. Backbone naturally wants to work with "chunks" of html. The only way to express those "chunks" is with tags.  Your issues are not caused by a limitation in backbone, rather that you are writing html that is not idiomatic. I would take a second look at how your markup is formed and try to make that work with backbone, not the other way around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to manually add the class-name. You can use the `className` property:

```
PhotoListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    className: 'photo_box',
```

---

Btw, I recommend this HTML structure:

```
<ul id="photo_list">
    <li>
        <img src="img/profiling/f_001.jpg" class="photo">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img/profiling/f_003.jpg" class="photo">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 22):

You could always use [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement):

> **setElement** `view.setElement(element)`
>
> If you'd like to apply a Backbone view to a different DOM element, use **setElement**, which will also create the cached `$el` reference and move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one.

and forget about `tagName` completely:

```
PhotoListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#tpl-PhotoListItemView').html()),
    render: function() {
        this.setElement(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XWEMg/

---

As an aside, [`<span>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html) is a poor choice for a container (even a temporary one) due to its limited [permitted content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content); you risk the browser rearranging your HTML to get something valid if you start throwing arbitrary HTML into a `<span>`. A [`<div>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html) is a much safer choice as it can hold pretty much anything.